# How to avoid duplicate messages emitted when using Flask-SocketIO + Redis Pub/Sub servers run on multiple processes load balanced by Nginx

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, redis, flask-socketio

I'm developing realtime message passing web app using websocket.
I used Flask-SocketIO for multiple websocket servers to emit messages which are generated from redis pub/sub.
Reading the Flask-SocketIO doc, I tried nginx sticky session and message queue for websocket to run websocket on multiple processes
The problem is messages are sent from all the processes to a client.

Nginx:

```
upstream app_server {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    server 127.0.0.1:5001;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwardded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://app_server/socket.io;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwardded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

app.py:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import sys
import os
import json
from multiprocessing import Process

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

process = None

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_CHANNEL = 'my-channel'

socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/')

def listen():
    redis_client = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT)

    pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe(REDIS_CHANNEL)

    try:
        while True:
            message = pubsub.get_message()
            if message is not None and message['type'] == 'message':
                data = message['data'].decode('utf-8')
                data = json.loads(data)
                print(data)
                socketio.emit('update', data)
    finally:
        pubsub.close()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    emit('connected', {'data': 'Connected successfully!'})

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = Process(target=listen)
    process.start()

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        port = 5000
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=port)
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            const socket = io.connect();

            socket.on("connect", () => {
                console.log("Connected to server");
            });

            socket.on("connected", (data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });

            socket.on("update", (data) => {
                console.log(data["msg"]);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

publish.py

```
import time

import redis

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_CHANNEL = 'my-channel'

while True:
    redis_client.publish(
        REDIS_CHANNEL,
        json.dumps(dict(
            msg='hello'
        ))
    )
    time.sleep(3)
```

When I run `app.py` on separate terminals:

```
python app.py 5000
```

```
python app.py 5001
```

and publish a message to the redis channel from another terminal by `publish.py`,
Two identical messages are displayed on client side console.
This is because a client access to one port is received messages from both `listen` processes run by app.py on 5000 and 5001 port.

What I want to do is to emit a message from a `listen` process run by app.py on 5000 port only to clients that was access to 5000 port through nginx.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BlueRobin Thank you for your advice. But I think there is not so many to trim to reproduce the problem. Instead I added index.html and script to publish message to redis channel (publish.py) for completeness.

Comment: I think there is some sort of misunderstanding on your part wrt the role the message queue plays. When using Flask-SocketIO, you just need to provide a queue, but you do not need to do anything with it, you just pass it to Flask-SocketIO to use. From the application you just need to use emit() as usual.

Comment: One redis server is used for two different purposes here. One is for message queue for multiple websocket workers to communicate and another is to listen for data from external sources from which message is generated to emit clients.  @MiguelGrinberg you mentioned the former, but the latter is needed for my app. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but if you broadcast something through your own Redis channel to all your hosts, and then each host uses Flask-SocketIO to broadcast something to all clients, then you are going to get duplicates, since each host will be sending a message to all the clients. The point I was trying to make is that if you need to send a message to all your clients, you have to issue one `emit()` call, from only one host. Which host you use doesn't matter, because Flask-SocketIO communicates with the other hosts over the queue to contact all clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code based on @MiguelGrinberg, and it worked as intended. I removed `listen()` from `app.py` and added `listen.py` as a new script.

app.py

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import sys

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import redis

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_CHANNEL = 'my-channel'

socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('Client connected')
    emit('connected', {'data': 'Connected successfully!'})

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def handle_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        port = 5000
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=port)
```

listen.py

```
import json

from flask_socketio import SocketIO
import redis

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_CHANNEL = 'my-channel'

socketio = SocketIO(message_queue=f'redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/')

def listen():
    redis_client = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST, port=REDIS_PORT)

    pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()
    pubsub.subscribe(REDIS_CHANNEL)

    try:
        while True:
            message = pubsub.get_message()
            if message is not None and message['type'] == 'message':
                data = message['data'].decode('utf-8')
                data = json.loads(data)
                print(data)
                socketio.emit('update_table', data)
    finally:
        pubsub.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    listen()
```

When I run two `app.py`, `listen.py` and `publish.py` on separate terminals:

```
python app.py 5000
```

```
python app.py 5001
```

```
python listen.py
```

```
python publish.py
```

No duplicate message is shown in client any more. Thank you!